# How to pause a process in u boot terminal

Tags: u-boot

I am a currently working with a u boot and the "mtest" command. In order to do some experiments, I would need to pause the "mtest" process, like a "ctr z" do. However, is seems that it is impossible to use "ctrl z" with u boot shell. Is there any other way to pause a process?

However, is seems that it is impossible to use "ctrl z" with u boot shell. I looked the u-boot documentation https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, but i didn't find any solution.

Is there any other way to pause a process? I am quite new to programming so sorry in advance if my question is dumb.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For interrupting commands in the U-Boot shell, please, use CTRL+C. If you use the sandbox, you would have to invoke it with *-t raw* otherwise CTRL+C will exit the program.

Answer (score 0):

U-Boot is not an OS or kernel, and has no concept of "*process*". U-Boot itself is the one & only execution path that the CPU executes until a kernel is loaded & executed.

U-Boot does not have a "*shell*" like a kernel; there's just a CLI. Each U-Boot command is executed as an ordinary procedure call; no "*process*" is created with a fork. A command can be run until it completes, or it can be aborted (if/when the procedure bothers to check if a `^C` was typed).

At best, you might be able to suspend/resume the command output to the serial console if flow-control is active (but that's not common).