# LED blinking from U-Boot

Tags: gpio, u-boot, led

Is it possible to implement a U-Boot subroutine for blinking LEDs via GPIO pins?
So when U-Boot shell is ready, first command of `bootcmd` will be `run start_blink;<other commands to boot to kernel>;`.
Can `run start_blink` executed somehow as a background job? Like in shell `./start_blink.sh &`.

Comment: U-Boot is a single-task environment. There is no "*background job*". You can certainly control a GPIO (for an LED), but timing would be tricky. Probably need to poll a hardware timer/counter to determine elapsed time. Issue is similar to handling a user abort; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75244741/how-to-pause-a-process-in-u-boot-terminal/75251240#75251240